# libgit2: obtain list of uncommitted changes

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I'm using libgit2 to manage installation and update of scripts for use with a program. I clone the remote repository to a local repository and already have working code to implement `git pull` (essentially `git fetch` and then `git merge`) based on the example code from the libgit2 repository.

However I have a "Manual update" button. What I want this to do is to show the user a list of changes that would be committed to the local repository if they accept the update. This is in case they have a particular favourite script that has been modified in the remote, so they can save a copy from the local repository or whatever.

I have been trying to implement this based on the status.c exemplar from libgit2, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. I'm not even sure if git_status_list_new() does what I want.

My code is shown below. I have set things up so I have 2 local clones of the scripts repository (one for making test changes in and one working repository that is used by the program). The working repository is one commit behind the remote. I have fetched but not merged the new commit from remote. At the command line `git status` shows:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However when I run my code using git_status_list_new(), I get nothing.

Here's the code:

```
struct status_opts {
    git_status_options statusopt;
    char *repodir;
    char *pathspec[MAX_PATHSPEC];
    int npaths;
    int format;
    int zterm;
    int showbranch;
    int showsubmod;
    int repeat;
};

int preview_update() {
    // Initialize libgit2
    git_libgit2_init();

    // Local directory where the repository will be cloned
    const gchar *local_path = get_scripts_repo_path();

    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    int error = git_repository_open(&repo, local_path);
    if (error < 0) {
        log_color_message(_("Error opening repository: %s\n"), "red", giterr_last()->message);
        return 1;
    }

    // Fetch changes
    lg2_fetch(repo);

    git_status_list *status;
    struct status_opts o;
    git_status_options_init(&o.statusopt, GIT_STATUS_OPTIONS_VERSION);
    o.repodir = g_strdup(local_path);

    o.format = FORMAT_LONG;

    if (git_repository_is_bare(repo)) {
        log_color_message(_("Cannot report status on bare repository"), "red",
            git_repository_path(repo));
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Run status on the repository
     *
     * We use `git_status_list_new()` to generate a list of status
     * information which lets us iterate over it at our
     * convenience and extract the data we want to show out of
     * each entry.
     */
    check_lg2(git_status_list_new(&status, repo, &o.statusopt),
        _("libgit2: could not get status"), NULL);

    if (o.showbranch)
        show_branch(repo, o.format);

    print_long(status); // <---- here is where the status should print the uncommitted changes

    git_status_list_free(status);
    g_free(o.repodir);
    debug_print("%s\n", git_pending_commit_buffer->str);
    log_message(_("Completed checking pending commits to scripts repository...\n"));
    if (!git_pending_commit_buffer)
        log_color_message(_("Local repository is up to date.\n"), "green");
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

`print_long()` is barely modified from the libgit2 examples directory: the first couple of lines are:

```
    size_t i, maxi = git_status_list_entrycount(status);
    printf("status items: %lu\n", maxi);
```

But the printf call prints "status items: 0", so the git_status_list appears to have 0 entries which is not what I would expect.

I know the call to (a slightly modified) `lg2_fetch()` works because despite not being able to get my list of pending changes, the pull functionality based on `lg2_fetch()` and then `lg2_merge()` works fine. Perhaps `git_status_list_new()` doesn't do what I need, or maybe I've misunderstood the exemplar. Anyway, any help you can offer on getting a list of pending commit messages would be fantastic.

Comment: I'm confused. The question title talks about uncommitted changes, but the question body question seems to be asking about changes to upstream refs. Which are you asking about?

Comment: My terminology is probably bad. I have fetched changes from the remote repository using the exemplar lg2_fetch() but not yet merged them into the local repository using lg2_merge(). (Both exemplar functions are lightly modified but they do work,) I want to print a list of the files that would be modified / added / deleted etc. if I went ahead and did the merge. (Or a list of the commit messages associated with the un-merged changes, I don't really mind, just something to give the user an idea of what changes they're about to agree to.)

Comment: The easiest [if inelegant] way may be to copy the existing work directory to a temp and do `git pull` on the temp copy. Then, `diff` the results. If the workdir was (e.g.) `/home/user/work`, then do: `cd /home/user ; cp -a work tmp ; cd tmp ; git pull ; cd /home/user ; diff -rup --exclude=.git work tmp` You can also do `git log` in both repos and diff the result as well

Comment: Or, after creating the `tmp` directory as above, getting the latest commit id from the original the temp copy and doing `git diff <commit_id> ...` in `tmp` (ought to work for `git log` as well).

Comment: I would prefer not to make a second copy of the repository. I'm kind of surprised if this is something difficult - surely it must be reasonably common to want to see what changes you're about to commit before you do it?